# I want the text chase the curser like train

Tags: javascript, html, css, paperjs

please take a look at this website:
http://alexandercoggin.com/

and see how the curser drags the text. I want to implement exact the same effect. here I have tried to use the paper.js library to do so but the result is not like what I want. Can anyone help me to write the code snippet please; There is no limitation in using any other library at all.

```js
// Setup Paper.js
paper.setup('myCanvas');

var word = 'Hello, World!';
var characters = [];

var offsetX = 0;
var offsetY = 0;
var characterSpacing = 20;
var chasingSpeed = 0.9;
var delayIncrement = 100;

for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  var character = new paper.PointText({
    content: word[i],
    fillColor: 'black',
    fontFamily: 'Arial, sans-serif',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 24,
    justification: 'center'
  });

  character.targetPosition = new paper.Point(0, 0);
  character.position = new paper.Point(0, 0);
  character.delay = i * delayIncrement;

  characters.push(character);
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
  var mousePosition = event.point;
  var cursor = document.querySelector('.custom-cursor');

  cursor.style.top = mousePosition.y - cursor.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
  cursor.style.left = mousePosition.x - cursor.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';

  // for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
  //     var character = characters[i];
  //     var targetPosition = mousePosition.add(new paper.Point(i * characterSpacing + 20, 0));

  //     setTimeout(function(char, targetPos) {
  //         char.targetPosition = targetPos;
  //     }, character.delay, character, targetPosition);
  // }

  var wordLength = word.length;
  var totalWidth = wordLength * characterSpacing;
  var angleIncrement = Math.PI * 2 / totalWidth;
  var initialAngle = Math.atan2(mousePosition.y, mousePosition.x) - Math.PI / 2;

  for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    var character = characters[i];

    var angle = initialAngle + angleIncrement * i;
    var radius = totalWidth / (2 * Math.PI);
    var targetX = mousePosition.x + Math.cos(angle) * radius;
    var targetY = mousePosition.y + Math.sin(angle) * radius;

    setTimeout(function(char, posX, posY) {
      char.targetPosition = new paper.Point(posX, posY);
    }, character.delay, character, targetX, targetY);
  }


}

function onFrame(event) {
  for (var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    var character = characters[i];
    var distance = character.targetPosition.subtract(character.position);
    character.position = character.position.add(distance.multiply(chasingSpeed));
  }
}

paper.view.onMouseMove = onMouseMove;
paper.view.onFrame = onFrame;

paper.view.onResize = function(event) {
  paper.view.viewSize = new paper.Size(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

paper.view.draw();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#myCanvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.custom-cursor {
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  /* Customize the cursor border color */
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
  /* Make the cursor transparent */
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/paper"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="custom-cursor"></div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please describe what is wrong with what you are seeing. On a quick run of your snippet on an iPad I see the canvas is too small and the characters pile up when I stop moving the cursor for example. What should they do? Currently they all seem to have the same target position.

Comment: @AHaworth aside from letters pile up which is not the problem in desktop the whole effect is not look alike to the one in website I provide as an example. I want the exact same effect and I don't know how . I couldn't even get the code from that website as it seems they packed the code with webpack or something like that

Comment: Have you tried anything to make the canvas cover the viewport? And could you say what other debugging you have done. I see the letters following the cursor OK when it's moving (within the confines of the canvas) but they pile up on top of each other when the cursor stops. I am on Windows10 Edge/Chrome.